# List of children with parents convert into parent with list of children

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have some models setup as follows:

```
public class Form
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubForm> SubForms{ get; set; }
}
public class SubForm
{
    public int SubFormId { get; set; }
    public virtual Form Form {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list like this:

```
List<SubForm> subForms; <-- already populated, each subform has a form parent.
```

How do I get it in a format like this optimally (lambda preferred)

```
List<Form> formsWithChildren;
```

Comment: `subForms.Select(i => i.Form).Distinct()`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the `FormId` then assign the grouped subforms to each new `Form` item as follows:

```
var formsWithChildren = subForms.GroupBy(s => s.Form.FormId)
                                .Select(g => new Form
                                {
                                    FormId = g.Key,
                                    SubForms = g.ToList()
                                }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**: if other properties exist then you would have to map them in the object initializer, but this could become tedious, and isn't the best option if you intend to reuse this type of query in other scenarios. I suggest creating a new `Form` object and mapping it using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

If you decide to use AutoMapper the approach would be similar to this:

```
var formsWithChildren = new List<Form>();
foreach (var item in subForms.GroupBy(s => s.Form))
{
    Form f = Mapper.Map<Form, Form>(item.Key);
    f.SubForms = item.Select(s => s).ToList();
    formsWithChildren.Add(f);
}
```

To learn more refer to the [AutoMapper site](http://automapper.org/).

Alternately, you could take an approach as follows, although this modifies the existing items so be aware of that.

```
var formsWithChildren = new List<Form>();
foreach (var item in subForms.GroupBy(s => s.Form))
{
    // re-use existing Form from grouping so it retains its assigned values
    Form f = item.Key;
    f.SubForms = item.Select(s => s).ToList();
    formsWithChildren.Add(f);
}
```

In both approaches shown above you will need to implement `Equals` on the `Form` class in order to GroupBy the `Form` instead of `FormId`:

```
public class Form
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubForm> SubForms{ get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        Form f = obj as Form;            
        return this.Equals(f);
    }

    public bool Equals(Form f)
    {
        if (f == null)
            return false;

        return this.FormId == f.FormId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.FormId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You could extend the equality and `GetHashCode` methods to use the properties to determine uniqueness. Currently it only relies on the `FormId`.

Comment: What if there are other properties in `Form`? They do not get copied

Answer (score 1):

```
formsWithChildren = subForms.Select(x => x.Form).Distinct().ToList();
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Will this put the related subforms under each form?

Answer (score 0):

Method without creating new form objects:

```
        //Populate subForms list of the forms
        subForms.GroupBy(x => x.Form).ForEach(x => x.Key.SubForms = x.ToList());
        //Select forms
        var forms = subForms.Select(x => x.Form).Distinct().ToList();
```